# Multi-bounty-ing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, accepted-answer

I'd like to consider having bounty separated, to some degree, from the accepted answer.

It would work something like this:

> Oh gee, I'm indecisive, and all these
>   answers are so scrumptious!  I want to
>   eat them all!
>
> Well... I'll choose this one as the
>   official answer, and they'll get the
>   full bounty.
>
> But these other four are nearly as
>   good, and they should be rewarded for
>   answering my call as well.  I will
>   give them the same award from my own
>   rep.

So if I offered a 150 point bounty, the first person would be accepted as the answer and go to the top, and receive the original 150 rep (100 from me, 50 from the system).

The next four would each receive 150 rep as well, from my rep.

It would cost me 750 rep to do so.  Other than the accepted answer, nothing else would change in the question.

Comment: @Shog9 - well, your version is certainly more concise, but I still think mine is funnier. #tags

Comment: @Adam: but yours demanded an apostrophe... (it was funny though)

Comment: True.  I didn't want to test the system to see if it accepted apostrophes in tags.

Answer (score 1):

This was completed a few months back. Obligatory blog link: [Improvements to Bounty System](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/)

Comment: Well, kind of. There's a 24 hour waiting period before you can actually award the bounty, so Pollyanna's theoretical test case will take eight days to complete.